# .NET, how to establish whether field has been nulled

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Easy one this, I am sure. I have tried to search, but no joy.

Suppose I have an object of type `A`, which has a public field `F` of type `B`. I create an instance of `B` and set `A.F=B`.

Result of `A.F == null` is False.
Result of `A.F is B` is True.

But then `B` is set to null. The `A.F` property still holds the handle to the old instance of `B`. And the runtime lookup of `A.F` still shows it as of type `B`. So the test `A.F == null` still gives False, the test `A.F is B` still gives True. Even though `B` has been trashed.

So how can I check the `A.F` property to see if its handle now points to a vanished object?

Answer (score 8):

A .NET reference never points to a vanished object; that is the entire point of GC. Your example describes two separate but identical references to a single object. Changing one reference does not change any other. Basically what you describe is like:

```
 int x = 1;
 obj.Foo = x;
 x = 0;
```

And then expecting obj.Foo to be 0. It won't be: it will be 1 until you change it. References work identically.

You did not "trash" the instance of `B`. That instance is still perfectly happy. You just removed one reference to it.

Put another way: on my Facebook, I list "Donna" as my wife. If I now clear that field (which I have no plans to do), I have not erased her account.

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid. Yes, there's still a pointer to it, so it is retained. Is there any way to trash all pointers to an object? I am using code at the moment, so object B has to keep a list of all references to it. So when I destroy B, it gets rid of all its pointers. It means that whenever I set a reference to B I have to make sure I call a method inside B so that B can record that reference.

Comment: @David no, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If `A.F == null` is `False` and `A.F` is `B`, then `A.F` and `B` are referencing the same object, which is not null.
If you think `B` should be null at this point in your code, because you set it to null before, you may have another bug in your code.